# VSTS/TFS Waiting for an enabled agent. All possible agents are disabled when using custom task conditions

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

```
TFS: 2017.3
Agent version: 2.112.0
```

I have a really simple build with a single Powershell script task. All the task does is a `Write-Host`, and it works fine.

I'm testing the conditional execution of this task based on the following condition:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['MyVariable'], 'SomeValue'))
```

As soon as I save this configuration and queue a build, it never starts and says:

```
Waiting for an enabled agent. All possible agents are disabled.
```

Config screenshot:

[image: Custom condition config]

Conditional tasks are a new feature since we upgraded. Is there something we need to enable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be related to the agent version, you need to download the latest build agent and configure it, then queue build with this agent.

**Test environment :**

TFS version: 2017.3

Agent version: 2.122.1

Build definition:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @JamesD, You are welcome, If this answer is helpful, you could accept it as the answer. So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: We tried to update the build agents yesterday but they remained on old version. Checking event log of server showed they were getting 407 authentication error from the proxy server and failing. Change request for server to bypass auth check scheduled for Monday. Will test again then but this likely seems to be the issue. At which point I’ll update here. Thanks

Comment: You could check it and kindly share the result here. In addition, you could also try to install the latest agent again.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Got it. If you have any questions about this ticket, you could also share it here and we will continue to solve the problem for you here. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: This is the answer, however I had to get around the 407 authentication error. The user running the `VSTS Agent` service had permission to make requests via the proxy, but the proxy log said the request was being made as the `system` user. I therefore followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=tfs-2017&tabs=windows#proxy-authentication) to temporarily add username/password as environment variable. Running `Update All` from the build agent page then worked successfully. Build agent is now `2.122.1` as per above.

Answer (score 1):

Your build agent version is from TFS 2017.1, after upgrading the server [you want to schedule an agent update for your agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#agent-version-and-upgrades).

[image]

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but your agent version is pre-condition-support.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing. This is correct, but see above regarding my issues with 407 unauthenticated errors when build agent tried to update. Once resolved, running `Update all agents` fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you're out of free build minutes and using a Hosted Agent. You get 1800 by default on the free tier within Azure DevOps.

I'd recommend checking your "Parallel Jobs" settings to see if you have any minutes remaining.

You can find your **Parallel Jobs** settings within the **Project Settings**, beneath **Pipelines**:
[Azure DevOps Parallel Jobs Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2WwG.png)

Comment: Our installation is on premises but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I could be way off here, but your post says that it's a build with a single Powershell task - `succeeded()` relies on the previous step succeeding, and for your example, there would be nothing that could succeed.

In your scenario, I might try putting another Powershell task with a different Write-Host before it, and put no condition on it, and then see if 1) the build finds an agent and runs, and 2) your second, conditional task runs successfully.

Comment: `succeeded()` can be put anywhere and just checks for failed tasks before it in the job. 0 failed tasks => success!

Comment: Yeah, I just verified that in a trivial pipeline. At the moment, I saw it and it just seemed... off.

Comment: Yes, the build doesn’t even start because it never gets past “All possible agents are disabled”.